# Map fitBounds() zooms into last marker in array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google Maps bounds function running as follows:

```
function intializeCustom() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-dir'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    });
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            radius: 3000,
            fillColor: '#2c3e50'
        });
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });
        circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
        google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'click', function(ev) {
            placeMarker(ev.latLng); //some function to place markers
        });
        bounds.extend(position);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}
```

Everything works properly except bounds. The map on render zooms in the last marker available in the `markers` array. Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new `LatLngBounds` at every iteration, so when you call `extend()` on it you'll always get the extents covering the current marker.

Just move the declaration before the loop and it should work.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    ...
}
```